# Only call 'git stash pop' if there is anything to pop

Tags: python, git

I am creating a post-commit script in Python and calling git commands using subprocess.

In my script I want to stash all changes before I run some commands and then pop them back. The problem is that if there was nothing to stash, stash pop returns a none-zero error code resulting in an exception in subprocess.check_output(). I know how I can ignore the error return code, but I don't want to do it this way.

So I have been thinking. Is there any way to get the number of items currently in stash? I know there is a command 'git stash list', but is there something more suited for my needs or some easy and safe way to parse the output of git stash list?

Also appreciate other approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: Check to see what `git stash list` outputs?

Comment: @IanAuld: I know what it outputs, one line per stash that was done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that!

Suppose that `git stash save` saves nothing, but there *are* already some items in the stash.  Then, when you're all done, you pop the most recent stash, which *is not one you created*.

What did you just do to the user?

One way to do this in shell script code is to check the result of `git rev-parse refs/stash` before and after `git stash save`.  If it *changes* (from failure to something, or something to something-else), you have created a new stash, which you can then pop when you are done.

More recent versions of Git have `git stash create`, which creates the commit-pair as usual but does not put them into the `refs/stash` reference.  If there is nothing to save, `git stash create` does nothing and outputs nothing.  This is a better way to deal with the problem, but is Git-version-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try calling `git stash show stash@{0}`.  If this returns successfully, there is something stashed.